# Django form keeps complaining required field

Tags: django, forms, model, field, required

The form submits but immediately says this field is required... although it was filled out. What am I doing wrong

In my view:

```
def fileupload(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.getlist('file_field'))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/fileupload/')
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'fileupload.j2.html', {'form': form})
    return HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>')
```

with this form:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    kit_number = forms.CharField(label="Kit number", max_length=100, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    file_field = forms.FileField(label='Upload kit result')
```

and template:

```
{% extends "menu.j2.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.is_staff %}
<h3>File upload</h3><br><br>
    <form action="/fileupload/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <table>
{{ form.as_table() }}
    </table>
</div>
    <input id="button" class="btn" type="submit" value="Sent">

    </form>

{% else %}
You are not authorized to see this page
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: show us the output of `print(request.POST)` and/or show us the part of your template with the <form>. And which field is required according to the error?

Comment: It's the file field, request.POST follows

Comment: First load: <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['otgwqypB0zpJjL52nIHCnDM9J7BJghmFx95U95P8GhhcVF'], 'kit_number': ['23423423'], 'file_field': ['20190boetgkhn.pdf']}>

Comment: in that case also `print(request.FILES)`

Comment: Files: <MultiValueDict: {}>

Comment: So apparently empty, but why

Comment: I selected a file

Comment: show us your template and/or HTML source (edit your question, the model is btw not relevant)

Comment: Done, instead of model, now template

Comment: I'm not authenticated apparently anymore after submitting the form? Does this make any more sense?

Comment: `{{ form.as_table() }}` should raise an error, it's `{{ form.as_table }}` (or are you using jinja2?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190933/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-niels).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set the form enctype.

```
<form action="/fileupload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```